# Add body class based on user field content

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

In Drupal, I've set things up so users can upload a "background image" to their account page. This is just a custom image field I've added.

How can I have a body class added based on whether a user has uploaded a background image, then removed if no background image has been uploaded. I've tried using the Context and/or Panels modules, but haven't had any luck.

Would really appreciate any insight or help anyone might have.

cheers,
ev

Comment: You could try looking into [views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) alternatively you could edit the page.tpl.php file to check if the field exists

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [preprocess_user_profile](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.pages.inc/function/template_preprocess_user_profile/7) in a custom module. Just check the user ($variables ['elements']['#account']) to see if the field exists, if it does then add your class, there's a good explanation [here](http://atendesigngroup.com/blog/adding-css-classes-fields-drupal) on how to add classes.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm hoping to have this background image appear not only on their user profile page, but also on other pages, for example: I setup a Views page that lists recent posts by that particular user. It would be great if the background image could appear here as well.

Answer (score 0):

Add some php code in your template (page.tpl.php - I guess your body tag is there) load current user, check for that custom field of yours and depending on that print out class directly into "style" body tag attribute.

Of course you can move the code into a function and place it into template.php and just call the function from template file, to have cleaner code.

Answer (score 0):

As in previous answers, to update nodes/user-profiles you will need to use a template preprocess or a *.tpl.php file to set a background image.

If you want it in a view, you can easily give the field a class like "background" and then use css to set the image to an absolute position as required!